# How can I list all IPs when Consul Cluster DNS is queried?

Tags: dns, cluster, consul

I have a 5 node [Consul Cluster](https://www.consul.io/intro/getting-started/join.html). When I run the DNS command below, it lists only three IPs at a time randomly. How can I have all 5 IPs listed at the same time (randomly) as opposed to three at a time?

```
dig @ 127.0.0.1 -p 8600 service_name.service.consul
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html

under dns_config, set enable_truncate to true

That should do it but I don't have a consul server at home to test on.

Comment: So in the config.json file, add the following: 
   {
    "dns_config": [
        {
            "enable_truncate": true
        }
      ]
}

Comment: Though this works, its kind of weird using "enable_truncate" after reading its definition. Is this the only way really?

Comment: The only one I could find.